# PySpark - Parquet - An error occurred while calling None.None

Tags: python, pyspark, hdf5, parquet

I have an hdf5 file with around 200 groups in it. So for each group I made a code that transform them into a parquet file with :

```
fastparquet.write(dir_name + '/' + metricname + '.parq', groupDataFrame)
```

After that I tried to read them, it is working nice except for some metrics where I got that error message : (I used HDFVIEW in order to see if there was something wrong in the values for this metric but I saw nothing, only integer values)

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\prog\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "C:\prog\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\uids2739\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in run_code(self, code_obj, result)
   2896             if result is not None:
   2897                 result.error_in_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
-> 2898             self.showtraceback()
   2899         else:
   2900             outflag = 0

C:\Users\uids2739\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only)
   1824                                             value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
   1825 
-> 1826                     self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)
   1827                     if self.call_pdb:
   1828                         # drop into debugger

C:\Users\uids2739\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.pyc in _showtraceback(self, etype, evalue, stb)
    509             u'traceback' : stb,
    510             u'ename' : unicode_type(etype.__name__),
--> 511             u'evalue' : py3compat.safe_unicode(evalue),
    512         }
    513 

C:\Users\uids2739\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\py3compat.pyc in safe_unicode(e)
     63     """
     64     try:
---> 65         return unicode_type(e)
     66     except UnicodeError:
     67         pass

C:\prog\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in __str__(self)
    419         gateway_client = self.java_exception._gateway_client
    420         answer = gateway_client.send_command(self.exception_cmd)
--> 421         return_value = get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, None, None)
    422         return "{0}: {1}".format(self.errmsg, return_value)

C:\prog\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    325             raise Py4JError(
    326                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
--> 327                 format(target_id, ".", name))
    328     else:
    329         type = answer[1]

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.None
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a problem of type because parquet doesn't support all.
I made the read request in sql form like this :

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`file.parq`")
```

giving me the error message :

```
AnalysisException: u'Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 46.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 46.0 (TID 46, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Parquet type not supported: INT32
```

So I changed the type int32 to float when creating this parquet file and problem was solved.